# SharePoint 2010 - Using REST to validate unique list item

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to validate that a duplicate combination of staff (person/group field) + parent ID (lookup field) does not already exist in a list. Below you can see that I've added an ajax call to the built-in PreSaveAction function which is called prior to form submission. When the PreSaveAction function returns true, the form will be submitted.

```
function PreSaveAction() { 
    $.ajax({
        url: listUrl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: validateUniqueStaff,
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Error: Problem with the AJAX request");
        }  
    }); 

    //if (validateUniqueStaff succeeds) return true, else return false
}
```

My trouble is that I can't figure out how to incorporate a deferred object here. I've tried running the ajax call synchronously instead, which works in Chrome, but not in IE8 (a requirement).

I'm absolutely stumped. Any advice would be hugely appreciated! Let me know if I can provide any other information.

Comment: how does your validateUniqueStaff function look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I proceed : I bind the click on the SAVE/OK buttons with jQuery, and do my stuff, and then I trigger the original code.

```
// bind the Save/OK buttons
$('input:button[id$="_diidIOSaveItem"]').each(function() {
  var $this=$(this);
  // save the "onclick" action to call it later
  $this.data("on-click",$this.attr("onclick"));
  // remove the default "onclick" action
  $this.attr("onclick","");
}).on('click',function(event) {
  // when clicking on these buttons do the below actions
  event.preventDefault();
  var $thisButton = $(this);
  // here you probably want to show some animation
  $thisButton.text("Checking duplicates...").prop("disabled",true);
  document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
  // you can put your code here
  $.ajax({
    url: listUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() {
      // your code
      // [...]
      // now we can go thru the normal action
      eval("!function() { "+$thisButton.data("on-click")+" }()");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error: Problem with the AJAX request");
    }  
  }); 
})
```

Comment: Really creative way of solving this. I'll give this a shot, thanks for the suggestion!